# How to get room id in laravel broadcast channel.php

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

Here is my js

```
var room_id = 3;
Echo.join('room'+room_id)
.listen('PersonalChat', (response)=>{
    // console.log(response);
 });
```

Here is PersonalChat.php

```
public $data;
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data=$data;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('room'."How to get room_id");
}
```

Here is My channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('rooom'.'How to get roomid', function ($user) {
 return EventHelper::Filter_UsingEvent($user);
});
```

I asked my question in my channels.php and PersonalChat.php 
**Again** May I say
My question is ** How to get room id ** in channels.php and PersonalChat.php

*Thank you all* 
*Sorry for my english skill*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can accept param in `channel.php` like `{roomId}` then in call back you will get that value

```php
Broadcast::channel('rooom.{roomId}'., function ($user,$roomId) { // $roomId will get
 return EventHelper::Filter_UsingEvent($user);
});
```

then in js

```js
var room_id = 3;
Echo.join('room.'+room_id)
.listen('PersonalChat', (response)=>{
    // console.log(response);
 });
```

and in `PersonalChat.php`

```php
public $data;
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data=$data;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('room'.$this->data->roomId); // you need to pass room id when event is trigger 
}
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#example-application-authorizing-channels

Comment: Thank @Kamlesh Paul, I found detail of the solution in laravel doc because of you.